# Config.properties returns value only when called twice

Tags: java, testing, junit

I have a program that I'm running tests for, and I have a particular method that attempts to access a `config.properties` file value. It returns null the first time I call it, and only returns a value after the second time it's called and I can't figure out why.

Here is my test in which I invoke the `getHostProp()` method twice

```
@Test
public void testHost() throws Exception {

    //when
    notMocked.getHostProp();
    assertEquals("tkthli.com", notMocked.getHostProp());
}
```

And the method in the class that it's testing

```
public class ConfigProperties {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    String propFileName = "config.properties";

    public String getHostProp() throws IOException {

        String host = prop.getProperty("DAILY-DMS.instances");
        if(foundFile()) {
            return host;
        }
        return "Error";
    }
}
```

This is a helper method I use to check if the path for config.properties is found. I'm not sure how it would influence this, but I'm adding it just in case anyone sees something in there that I don't which could be causing the problem.

```
public boolean foundFile() throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);

    if (inputStream != null) {
        prop.load(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
        return true;
    } else {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath.");

    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are throwing an exception if file not found, you can ignore the check `if(foundFile){..}` and directly give `fileFound(); return prop.getPr.....`.  The only return you get from `foundFile` is `true`, so I do not see a scenario where `return "Error"` will execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you pls try this...

```
if(foundFile()) {
   return prop.getProperty("DAILY-DMS.instances");
}
```

`prop` object is populated only after `foundFile()` call, however you are reading the data in a prior line.

Also, unless you are updating the config file in runtime, I would recommend you read the properties file one and store it in some static object or singleton. so that you can avoid any further file reads. just a thought..

Comment: ah I see. @redflar3 if it is trying to read the data before I populate it then why doesn't it give me a nullpointer exception?

Comment: @ralphie9224 There's nothing that tries to deref the null.

Comment: @ralphie9224 [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html] this page explains when a NPE can happen. One possible scenario in your code is `assertTrue` statement. The statement have to check the value of the arguments to check for equality and could throw an NPE. However `assertTrue` is internally implemented using String#equals. If you check the source code, you can see that it ignores any object (that is passed as argument) that is not an instance of `String`. hence the null referenced string object will be ignored and will return false.

Answer (score 1):

You did not load your property **'prop'** and trying to get **"DAILY-DMS.instances"** property!

The reason it worked for the second time because your method **foundFile()** actually loads the property to **'prop'** member variable and returns true during your first call to **getHostProp()** method.

During your second call, you have your **'prop'** member variable ready with the loaded value.

Hope I answered your question

Comment: @ralphie9224 - It won't throw a NullPointerException because you have initialized your 'prop' member variable like this:
"Properties prop = new Properties();"
Hence, you access any method from 'prop' now. If you read my answer above then you can understand what is happening.
You can find more info on how Properties.java work from java api-https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html